# While loop not continuing, exits after 1 iteration

Tags: c

Here is my code where I am trying to change one value and 3x3 matrix and then automatically changing all the elements of the matrix one by one. 
My problem is, `while` loop mentioned in the program should continue infinitely but it is not. It is exiting after one iteration. I've tried `gdb` but it is not showing any relevant information regarding this problem..

Code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matrix[3][3] = {0};
int row=0;
int col=0;
int i, j, k, l;
int seccount = 0;

char buffer[4096];
//buffer[0] = '\0';
void value_changer();
static void catch_signal(int signal)
{
    printf("*********************** Seconds : %d ******************************\n", seccount++);
    printf(buffer);
    puts("Second completes");
}

void value_changer(void)
{
    char temp[32];
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    matrix[0][0] += 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(matrix/*[i]*/) / sizeof(matrix/*[i]*/[0]); j++)
        {
            if(i==0 && j==0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]); k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < sizeof(matrix/*[k]*/) / sizeof(matrix/*[k]*/[0]); l++)
                    {

                        snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp) - 1, "%d ", matrix[k][l]);
                        strcat(buffer, temp);
                    }
                    strcat(buffer, "\n");
                }
                strcat(buffer, "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    //raise(SIGINT);
}

int main()
{
    if (signal(SIGINT, catch_signal) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //buffer[0] = '\0';
    while(1) // I want to continue the loop infinite time.
    {
        value_changer();
        raise(SIGINT);
        sleep(1); // This is to make sure that the each output is separated by 1 second delay.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Without giving me any error, it exits after one iteration.

GDB shows:

```
Starting program: /home/sujal.p/signal/test

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00130416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: Have you checked on the value of `sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0])`?

Comment: What *do* you see in gdb?

Comment: size is 3.. I've double checked by printing it..

Comment: @Rob.. Added the output of gdb

Comment: See the list of functions you can legally call in a signal handler, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal). Note that `printf()` is notably absent.

Comment: 1) don't use printf() and friends inside a signal handler 2) `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp) - 1,` : the `-1` is useless. 3) you seem to like strcat() a lot.

Comment: `raise(SIGINT);` stops your program.

Comment: Please try to narrow down the problem and present only the relevant code. If the problem is with the signal/raise mechanism, then we don't need to see the matrix stuff.

Comment: @wildplasser.. Well since this program is still in some more development and optimization, there are lot many things which I should change.. But this while loop is on more priority as of now...

Comment: @interjay.. I know but If I knew where exactly the problem then I've pasted the relevant code.. It was necessary to show what exactly being done in the while loop and the functions...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how signal() works on your system. I guess on your platform after the first SIGINT, the default signal action SIG_DFL is restored which causes the program to terminate the next time.
One option is to restore the handler everytime. Or better option would be to use sigaction().

Note: You shouldn't call printf from inside the signal handler (or any non reentrant function for that matter).

Comment: Reinstall the handler inside the handler `catch_signal()` i.e. call `signal(SIGINT, catch_signal);` inside signal() to reinstall.

Comment: @HirenPandya: `puts()` is just as bad.

Comment: According to you it depends on the system. But I have other code with me in which the while loop is working correctly. The difference between this code and the other one is that I haven't used buffer in that.. nothing else is changed..

Comment: @HirenPandya: Use a global `volatile sigatomic_t` to signal that the handler has been entered, then poll on that external to the signal handler and print there.

Comment: @Vatine.. Thnx but it is not helping.. this will cause the segmentation fault when I increase the matrix to 32x32..

Comment: @KingsIndian.. `signew.c:18:8: error: called object âsignalâ is not a function`..

Comment: @HirenPandya I am not sure why you get the error. What I say by "reinstall" is call the same signal() which you do in main() again in the catch_signal() function to reinstall the handler so that the next time SIGINT is received catch_signal() is called.